# Module version mismatch. Expected 43, got 14. while running node-imagemagick-native sample program

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, node-imagemagick

I installed the [node-imagemagick-native](https://github.com/elad/node-imagemagick-native) using command **npm install imagemagick-native**
The module is successfully installed with the following log

```
C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples>npm install imagemagick-native

> imagemagick-native@1.8.0 install C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modules\imagemagick-native
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modules\imagemagick-native>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\xz\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v0.12.7\node_modules\npm\bin
\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  imagemagick.cc
c:\program files\imagemagick-6.8.5-q16\include\magick/pixel-accessor.h(163): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'double' to 'const MagickCore::MagickRealType',
possible loss of data [C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modules\imagemagick-native\build\imagemagick.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xlocale(323): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc [C:
\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modules\imagemagick-native\build\imagemagick.vcxproj]
..\src\imagemagick.cc(131): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc [C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modu
les\imagemagick-native\build\imagemagick.vcxproj]
..\src\imagemagick.cc(304): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc [C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modu
les\imagemagick-native\build\imagemagick.vcxproj]
..\src\imagemagick.cc(344): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc [C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modu
les\imagemagick-native\build\imagemagick.vcxproj]
..\src\imagemagick.cc(364): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc [C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modu
les\imagemagick-native\build\imagemagick.vcxproj]
..\src\imagemagick.cc(405): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc [C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modu
les\imagemagick-native\build\imagemagick.vcxproj]
..\src\imagemagick.cc(572): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc [C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modu
les\imagemagick-native\build\imagemagick.vcxproj]
..\src\imagemagick.cc(742): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc [C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modu
les\imagemagick-native\build\imagemagick.vcxproj]
..\src\imagemagick.cc(817): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc [C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modu
les\imagemagick-native\build\imagemagick.vcxproj]
..\src\imagemagick.cc(890): warning C4344: behavior change: use of explicit template arguments results in call to 'v8::Local<T> NanNew<v8::String,char*>(A0)' [C:\Users\x
z\Downloads\test\examples\node_modules\imagemagick-native\build\imagemagick.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::String,
              A0=char *
          ]
          but the regular function 'v8::Local<T> NanNew(const char *)' is a better match
          with
          [
              T=v8::String
          ]
          if you expect 'v8::Local<T> NanNew(const char *)' to be called then you need to make it an explicit specialization
          with
          [
              T=v8::String
          ]
  win_delay_load_hook.c
     Creating library C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modules\imagemagick-native\build\Release\imagemagick.lib and object C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\no
  de_modules\imagemagick-native\build\Release\imagemagick.exp
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  imagemagick.vcxproj -> C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples\node_modules\imagemagick-native\build\Release\\imagemagick.node
PacificCX@0.0.1 C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples
└── imagemagick-native@1.8.0  extraneous


C:\Users\xz\Downloads\test\examples>
```

Now after installation, I tried to run the sample program

```
var imagemagick = require('imagemagick-native');
imagemagick.writeFileSync('image.jpg', imagemagick.convert({
    srcData: fs.readFileSync('before.jpg'),
    format: 'PNG',
    quality: 100 // (best) to 1 (worst)
}));
```

But got the following error...

[image]

Please look into the issue and oblige.

Comment: Have a look at this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602935/using-phantom-on-node-webkit/33605472#33605472

Comment: What exactly is not working? Also: what is your operating system? Do you have ImageMagick installed and operational?

Comment: Yes I have updated the logs of installation in this post. Do you thing these are the correct logs ?

My operating system in Windows 7 x32

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding module with `nw-gyp` as suggested in the linked answer?

Comment: Yes I rebuild the project from this directory ".\node_modules\imagemagick-native" by running this command "nw-gyp rebuild --target=0.12.3". The build was success. But this time running the sample code gave me this error in Node-webkit browser console.

"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: Have you solved the problem in question? If "Mismatch" error is gone, then probably yes. What generates `undefined is not a function` error? (Source is shown in the console)

Comment: No the problem is not yet solved. I don't know how its getting generated. I just mentioned and posted all the steps and logs. But the problem is still the same.